# Some divs "magically" disappear only in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am officially loosing my mental sanity, trying to figure out what's going on.

[My website home page](http://www.racebooking.net/it/moto/) has 2 columns.

1. Left column (white): which contains posts dynamically loaded with AJAX and
   which can scroll to infinite (like facebook home)
2. Right column (black): which
   contains a couple widgets and which after a certain scroll becomes
   FIXED (like facebook sidebar). The logic in pseudocode is basically:

.

```
if(scroll > X){
    right column -> position : fixed
}
else{
    right column -> reset position
}
```

Everything works fine in all browsers, except Google Chrome (tested on many computers).
[If you visit the website](http://www.racebooking.net/it/moto/) in fullscreen on HD monitor (sorry for popups, wee ned them to conver visitors), after an Y scroll point (where Y>X, so the right column is already fixed) the content on the right column goes all black and disappears for appearently no reason. Moreover, if you hover the mouse on it, it comes visible again. I tried with `z-index: 9999`or playing with `overflow` but that's not the issue.

It never ever happened anything like that, so i have no idea how to fix it. Any idea? Here are some screenshots of the issue, if you need:

Step 1: [Scroll < X: right column not fixed -> OK](http://www.download.racebooking.net/SO_QUESTION/example1.jpg)

Step 2: [SCroll > X: right column fixed -> OK](http://www.download.racebooking.net/SO_QUESTION/example2.jpg)

Step 3: [Scroll > Y: right content starts to disappear -> What the hell??](http://www.download.racebooking.net/SO_QUESTION/example3.jpg)

Step 4: [Scroll >> Y: right content disappeared completely -> WHAT THE HELL??](http://www.download.racebooking.net/SO_QUESTION/example4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just to think with you..

Can you add the z-index to this class?

```
    .trophy-box-home .trophy-driver {
       border-color: #333;
       z-index: 99;
     }
```

grts

Comment: Yes! But nothing changes... :\

Comment: maybe try to add 'display:block' on the 'a' arround the div 'trophy-driver' ? Should try things like this and test if this works..